# Edit Invoice PDF Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2

I wanted to make some changes in invoice pdf. For example, adding price + tax and display in the subtotal column. I have already created a custom module for editing the invoice. I have made some in the invoice like adding custom attribute value in the Invoice.

But I don't know how to add price and tax and display in the subtotal column.

[image]

In the DefaultInvoice.php, there is a draw function having items price values.

```
public function draw()
{
  ------------------------
  foreach ($prices as $priceData) {
        if (isset($priceData['label'])) {
            // draw Price label
            $lines[$i][] = ['text' => $priceData['label'], 'feed' => $feedPrice, 'align' => 'right'];
            // draw Subtotal label
            $lines[$i][] = ['text' => $priceData['label'], 'feed' => $feedSubtotal, 'align' => 'right'];
            $i++;
        }
        // draw Price
        $lines[$i][] = [
            'text' => $priceData['price'],
            'feed' => $feedPrice,
            'font' => 'bold',
            'align' => 'right',
        ];
        // draw Subtotal
        $lines[$i][] = [
            'text' => $priceData['subtotal'],
            'feed' => $feedSubtotal,
            'font' => 'bold',
            'align' => 'right',
        ];
        $i++;
    }

    // draw Tax
    $lines[0][] = [
        'text' => $order->formatPriceTxt($item->getTaxAmount()),
        'feed' => 495,
        'font' => 'bold',
        'align' => 'right',
    ];
}
```

Please let me know how to do addition.

Thanks.

Comment: You want to show **price+tax** in subtotal column here ?

Comment: Yes. I just want to add price and tax amount. and display it in the subtotal column.

Comment: I believe you displayed Price and Tax column there you just need to know how you can show price+tax in subtotal column?

Comment: Yes..................

Comment: Check the example invoice template image attached in this thread.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Nwem.png)

Comment: Yes, Give me few mins. checking some solution for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101232/discussion-between-sudhakar-sj-and-kishan-savaliya).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create `di.xml` file here in your custom module

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

Content for this file is..

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Items\AbstractItems">
        <plugin name="custom_plugin" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\AbstractPdfItemsPlugin" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"  />
    </type>
</config>
```

Now you need to create one Plugin here in your custom module

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/AbstractPdfItemsPlugin.php

Content for this file is..

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class AbstractPdfItemsPlugin
{
    protected $_taxData;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Tax\Helper\Data $taxData
    ) {
        $this->_taxData = $taxData;
    }

    public function aroundGetItemPricesForDisplay(
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Items\AbstractItems $subject, callable $proceed
    ){
        $result = $proceed();
        $order = $subject->getOrder();
        $item = $subject->getItem();
        if ($this->_taxData->displaySalesBothPrices()) {
            $prices = [
                [
                    'label' => __('Excl. Tax') . ':',
                    'price' => $order->formatPriceTxt($item->getPrice()),
                    'subtotal' => $order->formatPriceTxt($item->getRowTotal()),
                ],
                [
                    'label' => __('Incl. Tax') . ':',
                    'price' => $order->formatPriceTxt($item->getPriceInclTax()),
                    'subtotal' => $order->formatPriceTxt($item->getRowTotalInclTax())
                ],
            ];
        } elseif ($this->_taxData->displaySalesPriceInclTax()) {
            $prices = [
                [
                    'price' => $order->formatPriceTxt($item->getPriceInclTax()),
                    'subtotal' => $order->formatPriceTxt($item->getRowTotalInclTax()),
                ],
            ];
        } else {
            $prices = [
                [
                    'price' => $order->formatPriceTxt($item->getPrice()),
                    'subtotal' => $order->formatPriceTxt($item->getRowTotal() + $item->getTaxAmount()),
                ],
            ];
        }
        return $prices;
    }
}
```

I've updated below line in `else` condition

```
'subtotal' => $order->formatPriceTxt($item->getRowTotal() + $item->getTaxAmount()),
```

Hope this will work for you!